# Sharepoint online SSO - Missing parameters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, single-sign-on

I have an app that sends out emails to users with a link to a Sharepoint url, such as:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/mysite/mypage.aspx?param1=true#param2=false
```

When a user clicks on the link, if he/she is not already signed into Sharepoint, SSO takes over, redirects the user to the login page, and then redirects back to the original page. The issue is that after that redirect, the parameters are removed (so it ends up being `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/mysite/mypage.aspx`). Is there anything that can be done to prevent that from happening?